# SSIS Error: 0xC002F210" Query is too complex.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl, execute-sql-task

I am trying to Execute the following query using an **Execute SQL Task** using an Excel connection:

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverflow. Would you please format your question, so that error codes and all is formatted as code? Moreover, could you please provide some context, structure of database, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Executing SQL Query over Excel files is done by the Microsoft Access Database Engine which has many limitations.

Referring to the following article:

- [Error message when you run a query in Access 2007: "System Resource Exceeded" or "Query is too complex"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/918814/error-message-when-you-run-a-query-in-access-2007-system-resource-exce)

> **Cause**
>
> This problem occurs because Access 2007 has a 16-join limit. Additionally, large and complex query criteria in the WHERE clause can cause the "System Resource Exceeded" error message.
>
> **Workaround**
>
> To work around this problem, change your query so that there are no more than 16 joins.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if the Connection String is passed correctly or not.
2. Check if the Input and Output parameters are configured correctly or
   not.
3. Check if the result set parameters are binded correctly or not.

Comment: I have checked these things. Also, if i make the SQL statement shorter (by removing some UNIONS) then it is working fine.Still not able to figure out what exactly the error is.

Comment: If that is the case then you are left with only trail and error method. Remove one union per each execution and check after which union removal the package gets executed successfully.